# Issue with file versioning in Quasar using webpack-assets-manifest

Tags: vue.js, webpack, caching, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm facing an issue with file versioning in my Quasar project when using webpack-assets-manifest. The goal is to have unique filenames for static files (such as JavaScript and CSS) during each build to ensure proper caching and avoid users seeing outdated content.

I've configured my Quasar project to use webpack-assets-manifest for file versioning, but it seems that the filenames and hashes are not changing between builds. The generated files always have the same names and hashes, which defeats the purpose of versioning.

Here's a simplified version of my quasar.conf.js build section configuration:

```
build: {
  // ...

  extendWebpack(cfg) {
    // ...
    cfg.plugins.push(
      new WebpackAssetsManifest({
        // options
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I expected the webpack-assets-manifest plugin to generate new filenames with unique hashes for each build, but it's not working as intended. When I build, the generated files come with a hash, but when I build for the second time, the hashes remain the same as the first build.

Am I missing something in my configuration? How can I ensure that the file names and hashes are different for each build in my Quasar project using webpack-assets-manifest?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: which version of quasar you are using? 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using Quasar 2.2.11